# Предотвратить click()

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть квест, в рандомное время появляется попап, и кто первый кликнет получает приз
Но некоторые люди использую через консоль поиск элемента и click(), можно ли как-то это предотвратить, а учитывать только клик именно мышкой?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/mouse-clicks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. такое возможно. При клике мышкой в обработчик передается объект события, у которого есть поле [`isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)

> isTrusted - свойство объекта Event, доступное только на чтение. Принимает значение true, если событие было инициировано действиями пользователя, и false, если событие было создано или изменено скриптом, либо с помощью dispatchEvent.

```js
document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.isTrusted));

document.getElementById('click').click();
```

```css
#click {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="click">click me</div>
```

Comment: Э̶т̶о̶ ̶п̶о̶к̶а̶ ̶п̶о̶л̶ь̶з̶о̶в̶а̶т̶е̶л̶ь̶ ̶н̶е̶ ̶п̶р̶о̶п̶а̶т̶ч̶и̶т̶ ̶б̶р̶а̶у̶з̶е̶р̶

Comment: @andreymal, даже браузер не надо патчить, достаточно подменить обработчик клика :-)